# BufferedReader doesn't return

Tags: java, stream

I was given a task to create a java method which reads and returns the first line from the console without invoking `System.in.read(byte[])` or `System.in.read(byte[],int,int)`. (The `System.in` has been modified to throw an `IOException` if they are called.)

I came up with this solution:

```
InputStream a = new InputStream(){
    public int read() throws IOException{
        return System.in.read();
    }
};
BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(a));
return consoleReader.readLine();
```

No matter what I write into the console the `consoleReader.readLine()` method never returns!
How can I fix this?

Edit: I must use whatever InputStream System.in has been set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of creating a custom `InputStream` which only implements `int read()` is going into the right direction, unfortunately, the inherited `int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, which is eventually invoked for `BufferedReader.readLine` is trying to fill the entire buffer, unless the end of stream has been reached.

Therefore, you have to override this method as well, allowing earlier return if there are no more bytes available:

```
InputStream a = new InputStream(){
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return System.in.read();
    }
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int r=0;
        do {
            int x=read();
            if(x<0) return r==0? -1: r;
            b[off++]=(byte)x;
            r++;
        } while(r<len && System.in.available()>0);
        return r;
    }
};
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(a));
return reader.readLine();
```

Note that this follows the convention of reading at least one character in every read operation (unless end of stream has been reached). This is what the other I/O classes expect and `BufferedReader` will call `read` again, if no complete line has been read yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use can write it like this way:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(console.next());
```

Comment: This code will throw a NoSuchElementException with detail message: "No line found"

Comment: Certainly it is running fine for me:
Code:
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerClassTest
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println(console.next());
        }
}`

Comment: Unless we consider that the `Scanner` calls `System.in.read(byte[],int,int)` whitch throws an `IOException` as I already wrote it in the question. But the `Scanner` can't throw another `IOException`, so if it catches one, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, no System.in is in use.

```
    // using Console
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("No console: not in interactive mode!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
     System.out.print(console.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return if you provide enough text to fill 8192 bytes which is default char buffer size of `BufferedReader`. When you call `readLine()`, it will end up calling `a.read()`. It should supply at least 8192 bytes.